# DateTime.Now doesn't respond to time zone changes

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I built a clock using DateTime.Now and receive a time zone from a server.
The problem is that the DateTime keeps using the old time zone.

(I want it to start using the new time zone set when I receive without having to reboot)

How do I get around this problem?

Comment: How do you "receive a time zone from the server"?  Are you getting a TimeZoneInfo object, or is the local machine being set to a net time zone?

Comment: This is because DateTime represents the current time on the system to a certain level of accuracy.  It does not represent anything else.  There is a project by a well respected member of this site, that is an attempt to extend the DateTime, I believe its called Noda Time.

Answer (score 4):

You have to Clear the Time Cash after changing Time.
Use the following Command:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()
```

for more details:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/240283/datetime-is-not-reflected-instantly-when-time-zone-changes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to *convert* the current local time into the desired timezone. Something like this:

```
var timeInServerTimezone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, timeZoneInfoReceivedFromServer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the TimeZone class instead of DateTime? I am not sure if it will make a difference but worth taking a look.

```
 DateTime baseUTC = new DateTime( 2000, 1, 1 );
 TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
 DateTime localTime = localZone.ToLocalTime( baseUTC );
```